# Create a game with participants

Tags: php, security, crm

I am currently developing a prediction game for my circle of friends for the World Cup.

In short, it should be pretty simple.
I would like to create a website in which an unauthenticated user can create a game (prediction game). He only has to enter a game name and his e-mail address, the password will automatically be sent by e-mail (generated). So far so good. In addition I would like it also a participant code generated with which my friends can register. (Everyone has the same registration code for each game).

The admin can edit the game etc.
The participant can simply bet on the team and possibly win points.

Now to my question: The admin and the participant should both be able to log in only with the code so not with username, e-mail or whatever.
How can I make sure that it is the right admin or participant?
Normally one compares yes the input of "username" and "password" and can thus ensure who it is. I now have only the password and do not know how I can implement this safety.

Answer (score 0):

The admin 's registration code for the game could be longer than the others. The last characters can identify that the participant is the admin.